# SqlAlchemy: How to implement DROP TABLE ... CASCADE?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to drop tables in a PostgreSQL database that have foreign key constraints and require `DROP TABLE ... CASCADE`.

I could execute raw SQL: `engine.execute("DROP TABLE %s CASCADE;" % table.name)`.
However, I would like to implement this behaviour such that I can do `table.drop(engine)` for the `postgresql` dialect.

How would one approach this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can [customize the compilation of constructs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#changing-compilation-of-types) like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import DropTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

@compiles(DropTable, "postgresql")
def _compile_drop_table(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return compiler.visit_drop_table(element) + " CASCADE"
```

This appends `CASCADE` to the `DROP TABLE` statement issued for the postgresql dialect while keeping all other dialects the same.

Comment: A little future-proofing for Python 3:
return f"{compiler.visit_drop_table(element)} CASCADE"

Comment: For anyone looking for the typed hint version of this answer: https://gist.github.com/giuliano-oliveira/9fef9352395ccc4dc0304c23a5cdd3a9

Answer (score -1):

You need the data in `pg_constraint`, which is [a rather complicated table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html), that handles all constraints, including check constraints and foreign keys. Fortunately, what you want is fairly straightforward.

In order to get the list of all of the tables referencing table `foo`, you can do something like:

```
SELECT conrelid
  FROM pg_constraint
  WHERE confrelid = <the relid for foo>;
```

That gets you a list of table relids. But you probably don't want to deal with relids, so let's make it a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT r.schemaname || '.' || r.relname
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables r, pg_constraint c, pg_stat_user_tables s
  WHERE
    s.relid = c.confrelid AND
    c.conrelid = r.relid AND
    s.relname = 'foo';
```

That returns a list which you can then loop through and issue individual `DROP TABLE` statements.