# Postgres can't drop table when view is present

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing data to postgres tables from python with `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2` using the `if_exists='replace'` option in `to_sql()`.  This drops the table, then recreates it. However, if I have a view defined that uses that table, the `to_sql()` command fails, as postgres won't drop the table. Is there anyway around this other than manually dropping the view first, the recreating it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aim to DROP a TABLE with related objects depending on it such as VIEW, you need to use CASCADE keyword to force to DROP related objects as well (this is a recursive operation).

See PostgreSQL [dependencies tracking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-depend.html) for details:

> To ensure the integrity of the entire database structure, PostgreSQL
> makes sure that you cannot drop objects that other objects still
> depend on.

By default it is not feasible, actually creating a VIEW on a table is a convenient way to prevent this TABLE to be dropped accidentally. Anyway, you may also want to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678336/sqlalchemy-how-to-implement-drop-table-cascade) to implement CASCADE beahviour with SQLAlchemy.

Then it is still your responsibility to recreate missing related objects after you recreated the table. SQLAlchemy seems to have no representation for related views. But it there is a [package to create views](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-views/) and may fill this the gap in some extent (not tested).

So, it cannot be handled by SQLAlchemy alone. You will need instead a script/function that plays DDL statements to recreate your dependencies (maybe using the above mentioned package).

If you can recreate it using pure SQL standard (or using package) then you will not loose the benefit of SQLAlchemy ORM (at least the capability to abstract Database engine and being portable to another one).

About dependencies tracking, an easy way to see what related object should be recreated is:

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE mytable CASCADE;
ROLLBACK;
```

You can also use the function  [`pg_depend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html) which is very convenient but PostgreSQL specific.